# Special Identity Security Group in AD

Tags: security, permissions, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

In activity directory is there a way to create a security group that utilizes a special identity? I can explain why I’m trying to do this but typing it out is getting a little wordy.

What I’d like to put together is a group that is Authenticated Users except CREATOR OWNER.

I want this group in order to deny Authenticated Users permissions unless they have the CREATOR OWNER permission of a folder or file.

My problem being, since the user who is CREATOR OWNER is also Authenticated User, if I deny Authenticated User that overrides the Allow permissions I've set for CREATOR OWNER.

There's probably no way to do anything like this but just looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. Deny entries always take precedence over Allow entries, *unless* the Deny entry is inherited and the Allow one is explicit.

But there's a much better way to accomplish what you're going for. Simply remove the Authenticated Users entry from the ACL. (You may have to disable inheritance first.) If a user does not match any ACL rules, the default action is Deny. Therefore, if you just assign `CREATOR OWNER` the desired rights on the parent folder and stop the Authenticated Users entry there from applying to files, only the person that creates a file will have access to it.

Also note that `CREATOR OWNER` isn't really a person; its entry on a folder gets replaced with a user-specific one when that user creates a file in that folder. That only happens once; it's not a dynamic thing that always references the owner.

Further reading: [NTFS Permissions, Part 2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.01.howitworksntfs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the Special Identities can not be utilized in this way.